# Is Unirest java library responses encrypted?

Tags: java, http, unirest, unirest-java

I'm using unirest library to implement http responses like get,post,put and delete. As HTTP doesn't uses encryption - I think unirest doesn't encrypt. Correct me if I'm wrong. Any explaination appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure it's not httpS?

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to expose your application directly on the internet, but to have a public-facing web sever that supports https and routes the requests to your application.

Answer (score 0):

http just is a web protocol.there is no concreted with encryption data

Comment: What do you mean with _"there is no concreted with encryption data"_?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).